# Access an id from usercontrol in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So i have the usercontrol named `footer` which contains the navigation to the website, I'm trying to append the `active` css class to the div in usercontrol  so that the user

This is my `footer.ascx`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Footer.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Footer" %>
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="Footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row"> 
            <button id="ImgOption1Guru" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" runat="server" type="button" onclick="location.href='Option1.aspx';">Option 1</button>
            <button id="ImgCmnyInfo" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href='CompanyInfo.aspx';" runat="server" type="button">Info</button>
            <button id="ImgInteract" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href='Interact.aspx';" runat="server" type="button">Interact</button>
            <button id="ImgActions" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href='Actions.aspx';" runat="server" type="button"> Actions</button>
            <button id="ImgStatus" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href='Status.aspx';" runat="server" type="button">Status</button>            
          </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I've used this footer in my `aspx` page via

```
<div id="footer"><ucl:Footer ID="foot" runat="server" /></div>
```

Now i want to add the css class `active` to the `button id` on their respective pages
. So far i've tried adding the code down to the respective pages and it doesn't seem to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("ImgActions");
    x.classname += " " + active;
</script>
```

what should i do to access the id of tag in the usercontrol in my aspx page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ClientID` of the control because the id of control will be changed when html is generated by asp.net as you do not have [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not set to `static`. also `classname` should be `className`

```
var x = document.getElementById("<%= ImgActions.ClientID %>");
x.className += " " + active;
```

> ASP.NET provides multiple algorithms for how to generate the ClientID
>   property value. You select which algorithm to use for a control by
>   setting its [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. The algorithms are identified
>   by the ClientIDMode enumeration, Reference.

You can use ClientIDMode static as you have javascript in different control that does not know ImgActions.

Html

```
<button id="ImgActions" ClientIDMode="static" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" onclick="location.href='Actions.aspx';" runat="server" type="button"> Actions</button>
```

Javascript

```
 var x = document.getElementById("ImgActions");
 x.className += " " + active;
```

Comment: `The name 'ImgActions' does not exist in the current context.` i get that when i try to use ClientID, Also could you link me on how to use clientID properly ?

Comment: You can use ClientIDMode static as you have javascript in different control that does not know ImgActions.

Comment: it works but the active class doesn't show up(doesnt get appended).when checked via firebug it gives me `TypeError: x is null error source line: var x = document.getElementById("ImgActions");`

Comment: You need to put the javascript code after all the html is rendered, if you can use jquery then look at document.ready event